# Absolutely no borders in html

Tags: html, css, border

Probably a really dumb question, but, if I make a simple page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_Pz8Gm0-zlrU/S8NOCkLAzQI/AAAAAAAAAAc/d8vXcPvbAlE/s1600/Seal_cub_1280x800.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

The image has a border at the top and left. Even if I set `body { border-width: 0px }` and `img {border: 0px}` in css. How do I get rid of it? What else needs to be zero?

Comment: You're *sure* it's a `border` and not an `outline`?

Comment: Then add `outline: none;` to your CSS (in which you've declared `border`) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @DavidThomas Turns out it was padding, thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* {margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}
```

`*` is a universal selector.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 html,body{margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}
```

and [try this to reset the css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: If you're going to copy a reset style-sheet (and you may have arrived at this by yourself and if so I do apologise), please cite your source(s).

Comment: No worries (and by all means *show* the contents of the reset stylesheet), it's just that I think it deserves attribution is all. =)